# How to fix with custom image from slurm-gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, slurm

I distributed slurm-gcp using Terraform through the GitHub and it was available successfully. Source:

[Slurm on Google Cloud Platform](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm-gcp)

But I want to change the image I use when using node to a custom image.

I am trying to edit `/slurm/scripts/config.yaml`.

Among the contents of the file:

```
image: projects/schedmd-slurm-public/global/images/family/schedmd-slurm-20-11-7-hpc-centos-7
```

I want to edit the part.

How to reroute this part to my custom image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create your own image.

Create a new VM with the image you want to modify; make appropriate changes and stop the VM. Then create a new image from the VM's disk.

Next [create a custom image from that disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#create_image) and your path in the `config.yaml` file can look like this:

`image: projects/my-project-name/global/images/your-image-name`

You can get exact path to your custom image by running:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wb)$ gcloud compute images describe your-image-name | grep selfLink
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/wb/global/images/your-image-name
```

Comment: I have additional questions.
When I create an image, is the network-tag saved as well?

Comment: No - [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) are attached to the VM's so you have to add it while creating a new VM. However you can create an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates) and add your tag with your custom image there so you will have a starting point to create new VM's with a few clicks.